# Онлайн-перевод API

Tags: c#, перевод

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как с помощью `google api` или другого сервиса получить список переведенных слов и желательно и их артикль (т.к. в немецком это важно).

На сколько я понял, API для извлечения рода существительного нет и надо тупо загружать страницу для перевода, а потом "что-то" писать, что б вытягивало с необходимых частей страницы нужные мне данные.   
Или это ломовой метод и так не делается? 
(я пока не программист, сорри, если где-то пишу чушь).
Буду рад увидеть любые ответы.

Зараннее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте [API Яндекс.Перевода](http://api.yandex.ru/translate/): + [пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/168101/) запроса из программы, ответ в виде XML.

Если Google, то API есть, он платный: [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/?hl=ru).

Если Вам для сайта, а артиклем и озвучкой слов, крутая штука: [DictionaryBox](http://dictionarybox.com/) - пример находится внизу страницы, доступно много языков.

Comment: Спасибо, мне вообще не для сайта. Для себя (пока) хочу прогу сделать.
Если б я шарил бы в том, что за код "оно" мне написало. Так а я не оч понял, где там а озвучка? А можно как нибудь открыть окно того же самого лингво и когда пользователь вводит значения в программе, она бы открывала сайт и заносила в определённое поле слово, а потом бы брала перевод, как бы типа с сайтом работаешь, но пользователь этого всего не видит, а получает только перевод

Comment: Лучше не парится и поискать открытый API для переводов, любой: дохлый кривой неполный, иначе себе дороже выйдет, будете распарсивать непонятно как и непонятно чем, а очередная обнова на сайте загнет вашу прогу. Уж тем более если вы не понимаете что там написано! А с API будете просто делать Web request -> получать ответ, и грызть семечки.

Comment: Даже я за Вас уже поискал, используйте Яндекс: http://api.yandex.ru/translate/

Тут пример есть, как запросы делать и в XML результаты получать: http://habrahabr.ru/post/168101/
по мне так и придумать лучше нельзя.

Answer (score -1):

Почти все API платные, смотрите в сторону тех на которых есть бесплатные знаки:
https://translated.com/, https://translate.google.com/, https://cloudapi.stream/